# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:db\Peticiones.php on line 24

Tags: php, mysql

queria saber si me podrian colaborar con este error que lanza al querer hacer un registro de usuarios

La linea que esta provocando el error es la siguiente:

`$sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql)`;

Este es el documento de Peticiones:

```
<?php
include 'Conexion.php';

class Peticiones
{

    private $dbname;
    private $conn;
    private $db;

    /*public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = new Conectar();
    $this->dbname = $this->conn->dbname;
    $this->db = $this->conn->getConexion();
    }*/


    //Sentencia para registro Usuarios 

    public function registroUsuario($datosUser)
    {
        try {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->dbname.usuarios (nombres, primer apellido, segundo apellido, num_documento, clave, correo, telefono_usuario, id_tipo_documento) VALUES (:nombres, :primer_apellido, :segundo_apellido, :num_documento, :clave, :correo, :telefono_usuario, :id_tipo_documento);";

            $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':nombres', $datosUser['nombres']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':primer_apellido', $datosUser['primer_apellido']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':segundo_apellido', $datosUser['segundo_apellido']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':num_documento', $datosUser['num_documento']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':clave', $datosUser['clave']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $datosUser['correo']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':telefono_usuario', $datosUser['telefono_usuario']);

            $sentencia->bindParam(':id_tipo_documento', $datosUser['id_tipo_documento']);


            $sentencia->execute();

            $LAST_ID = $this->db->lastInsertId();

            return $LAST_ID;
            $this->db = null;

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {                
            die($e->getMessage());               
            return "error";                
        }            
    }    
}
```

## Conexion.php

```
<?php 
class Conexion{

 public function __construct(){ 
    $host = 'localhost';    $db   = 'newproyect';   $user = 'root';    $pass = '';
     try{    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);   }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Conexion fallida".$e->gettMessage(); exit();

    }   public_function getConexion(){
      $conexion->setAtribute(PDO:ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    return $conexion;
  } 

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Puedes indicar el contexto donde usas el código? Lo que muestras es una clase, pero debes estar creando una instancia de la clase en alguna parte... Lo que parece ocurrir es que la conexión no es válida, parece que tienes cierta confusión organizando el código. Incluyes un archivo `Conexion.php` en la clase y tienes un intento de conexión (comentado)  en el constructor. Eso que hay en el constructor parece muy disparatado: `$db, $conn` e intento de traer a tu actual clase una instancia de la clase `Conectar`, etc.

Comment: Es el fallo que tengo, ya que no se que funcionalidad tiene el getConexion que esta en la class Peticion, y lo tengo en la Conexion.php  pero ahora me sale este error en la conexion --> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'getConexion' (T_STRING) in  ...                     Y ademas  de lo que me comentas, en cambio en la conexion.php  no tengo un class sino un function, hay algo malo en eso ?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema de organización de código.

Asumo que este archivo pone en el contexto la clase `Conectar` que intentaste usar en el constructor:

```
include 'Conexion.php';
```

Ahí ya tenemos un problema de convención de nombres, no es grave, pero una clase no debería tener un nombre de un verbo, mejor llamarla `Conexion`, como el archivo.

En la clase `Peticiones`, dado que parece que existe para lanzar consultas a la base de datos, necesitas de alguna manera un objeto conexión válido.

Asumamos que el método `getConexion()` de la clase `Conectar` devuelve ese objeto. Entonces puedes escribir tu clase así:

```
<?php 
    include 'Conexion.php';

    class Peticiones
    {

        private $db;
        private $dbname;

        public function __construct(){
            $conn = new Conectar();
            $this->dbname = $this->conn->dbname;
            $this->db = $conn->getConexion();
        }


        //Sentencia para registro Usuarios 

        public function registroUsuario($datosUser)
        {
            try {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->dbname.usuarios (nombres, `primer apellido`, `segundo apellido`, num_documento, clave, correo, telefono_usuario, id_tipo_documento) VALUES (:nombres, :primer_apellido, :segundo_apellido, :num_documento, :clave, :correo, :telefono_usuario, :id_tipo_documento);";
                $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql);  
                $sentencia->bindParam(':nombres', $datosUser['nombres']);   
                $sentencia->bindParam(':primer_apellido', $datosUser['primer_apellido']);   
                $sentencia->bindParam(':segundo_apellido', $datosUser['segundo_apellido']); 
                $sentencia->bindParam(':num_documento', $datosUser['num_documento']);   
                $sentencia->bindParam(':clave', $datosUser['clave']);   
                $sentencia->bindParam(':correo', $datosUser['correo']); 
                $sentencia->bindParam(':telefono_usuario', $datosUser['telefono_usuario']); 
                $sentencia->bindParam(':id_tipo_documento', $datosUser['id_tipo_documento']);
                $sentencia->execute();
                $LAST_ID = $this->db->lastInsertId();
                $this->db = null;
                return $LAST_ID;    
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {                
                die($e->getMessage());               
                return "error";                
            }            
        }    
    }

?>
```

#### Uso

```
$mPeticion=new Peticiones();
$msg=$mPeticion->registroUsuario($variableDatos);
echo "ID insertado: $msg";
```

**NOTA:**

En la clase he puesto el cierre de la conexión antes del `return`, cuando usas `return` nada de lo que está más para abajo se ejecuta.

He suprimido la propiedad `private $conn`. Creo que no es necesaria.

---

### EDICIÓN

#### Corregir la clase `Conexion`

La clase para conectar tiene varios errores, por tanto hay que corregirla. Modifícale de este modo:

```
<?php
    class Conexion{

        private $conexion;

        public function __construct() {
            $host = 'localhost';    
            $db   = 'newproyect';   
            $user = 'root';    
            $pass = '';

            /*Es mejor pasar las opciones en el constructor*/
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );

            try{
                $this->conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset="utf8"', $user, $pass, $options);

            }catch(PDOException $e){

                echo "Conexion fallida".$e->gettMessage(); 
                exit();
            }
        }

        public function getConexion() {
            return $this->conexion;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Cordial saludo, gracias por tu ayuda, aunque aun me genero un fallo en el archivo de *Conexion.php* con el getConexion ya que me aparece unexpected ...

Comment: @Solarte si quieres coloca en tu pregunta el contenido completo de `Conexion.php`... puedes quitar datos sensibles el mismo cambiándolos por *****

Comment: Esta es la conexion                                                                            <blink><?php 
class Conexion{
public function __construct(){

    $host = 'localhost';
 $db   = 'newproyect';
 $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

 
 try{
      
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);
  }catch(PDOException $e){

     echo "Conexion fallida".$e->gettMessage(); exit();
     
 }
 public_function getConexion(){
    $conexion->setAtribute(PDO:ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   return $conexion;

 } 
 }
?></blink>

Comment: No se aun como colocarlo en caja de texto :1, disculpa

Comment: En tu pregunta, editala y pon ahí el código del archivo.

Comment: @Solarte hay varios errores en tu clase de conexión. Revisa la última parte de mi respuesta, donde he puesto una corrección de dicha clase. Prueba con el código íntegro como te propongo.

Answer (score 1):

**El error te esta indicando que tratas de invocar al método `prepare()` sobre una propiedad cuyo valor es `null`, lo que ocurre con una variable/propiedad declarada pero no inicializada.**

El error sería consecuencia del siguiente bloque comentado en tu código:

```
/*public function __construct(){
    $this->conn   = new Conectar();
    $this->dbname = $this->conn->dbname;
    $this->db     = $this->conn->getConexion();
}*/
```

donde se debía *inicializar la conexión* antes de poder trabajar con ella.

*Si el bloque no estuviera comentado* aún podrías tener un nulo en `$db`, dependiendo de la implementación de la clase `Conectar`, donde un nulo podría ser devuelto en caso de fallar el procedimiento para establecer la conexión.

Podrías controlar este error concreto por ejemplo con la siguiente modificación de tu código.

```
public function registroUsuario($datosUser)
{
    if (! $this->db) {
        die('ERR -> No hay conexión con la BD');
    }

    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->dbname.usuarios (nombres, `primer apellido`, `segundo apellido`, num_documento, clave, correo, telefono_usuario, id_tipo_documento) VALUES (:nombres, :primer_apellido, :segundo_apellido, :num_documento, :clave, :correo, :telefono_usuario, :id_tipo_documento);";
        $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta hacer la conexión con la variable $db

```
$db = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contra, $bd);
```

Una vez hecho esta conexión puedes acceder a los métodos

```
$this->db->prepare("SQL QUERY");
```

Si ya obtienes la conexión en esta linea `$this->db = $this->conn->getConexion();`

Solo descomentala para que haga el proceso de conexión.

o si usas PDO

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$bd", $usuario, $contra);
```

Comment: Disculpa, la conexion con la variable $db lo haria en el mismo formulario de peticiones, o en la Conexion ?

Comment: Si puedes anexar el archivo Conexion.php para ver los métodos y revisar si puedes usar eso que ya tienes

Comment: El código es PDO, si observas bien. Y también está dentro de una clase que conecta a PDO, sólo que el código de conexión aparece comentado, en el constructor.